# Cannot solve Classnotfound Exception

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, spnego

I hope the answer will be stupidly simple, but I cannot get the following test program running due to a classnotfound exception:

```
import java.net.URL;

import net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpURLConnection;

public class HelloKeytab {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "krb5.conf");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "login.conf");

        SpnegoHttpURLConnection spnego = null;

        try {
            spnego = new SpnegoHttpURLConnection("spnego-client");
            spnego.connect(new URL("http://as1.test.local/hello_spnego.jsp"));

            System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " 
                    + spnego.getResponseCode());

            System.out.println("HTTP Status Message: "
                    + spnego.getResponseMessage());

        } finally {
            if (null != spnego) {
                spnego.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I installed JDK7 and set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable as an Administrator.
I am working on a Windows XP machine as a regular domain user while compiling and running.

I have the `spnego-r7.jar` in the same directory as the `HelloKeytab.java` and I compiled with:

```
javac -cp .;spnego-r7.jar HelloKeytab.java
```

which succesfully creates the class.

When I run the program with:

```
java -cp .;spengo-r7.jar HelloKeytab
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/spneg
o/SpnegoHttpURLConnection
        at HelloKeytab.main(HelloKeytab.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpUR
LConnection
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

The `spnego-r7.jar` can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/spnego/files/

What I am doing wrong that it doesn't find my class?

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure the jar is in the folder?

Comment: Can you please try by giving complete path of jar file ?

Comment: Strangest thing. I copied all the files from the user directory\My Documents to C:\test\ and the classpath error is gone, even without specifying the complete jar path.

Comment: logged out and logged in againnand the same error is back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoClassDefFoundError are always because of incorrect or incomplete builds, or errors in class path.

I always go through the following checklist when getting this error:

- Clean project
- Check files and directories
- Check build path

Try again. Never fails. :)

Comment: Indeed, a stupid fault. Solved it by adding %JAVA_HOME%/bin to my global PATH environment variable.